# ASP.NET MVC 1 .. Ajax.BeginForm within Html.BeginForm. How to post without stopping and starting Html form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

For example..

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
<%= html.textBox(Model.IwantThisField)%>

<%using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", new AjaxOptions { fancy ajax options })) %>
   <%{%>
     <label for="stringVar">This is sent to Action</label>
     <input type ="submit" id="button" />
   <%}%>

<%= html.textBox(Model.IalsoWantThisField) %>
<input type="submit" id="mainBtn"/> 
<% } %

>
```

Any more information needed I will provide. This has had me stumped on a Fridat afternoon which is not at all fun. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Nesting forms is not allowed in any HTML standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest a form within a form. What are you trying to accomplish?
You could remove your Ajax.BeginForm, change the input from type submit to button, then capture the button click with JQuery and make your ajax request with $.post.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
<%= html.textBox(Model.IwantThisField)%>

     <label for="stringVar">This is sent to Action</label>
     <input type ="buttom" id="button" />


<%= html.textBox(Model.IalsoWantThisField) %>
<input type="submit" id="mainBtn"/> 
<% } %

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var value = $('#stringVar').val();
        var data = {stringVar: value};
        $.post('Your action URL',data,function(data){
             //On complete Ajax request javascript.
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Basically the user needs to search a separate set of data to the original form that they are filling out. This set of data is linked to the original set but only by an ID, I wanted to make it so they could have a whole separate search for this data so they could see the contents of the data attached to that ID mentioned.

Comment: I'll give your code a whirl and see how it goes. Thanks for that anyway, I'm new to this technology so it didn't occur to me to use JQuery.